# Usage of log4net in .net petshop 4

Tags: .net, logging, log4net

I have a question regarding log4net usage for logging information in .net petshop 4 application.How do I use it to log informaton related to size of the message and time at which logging occurs.Please help !I have tried opening .net petshop using visual c# express edition 2008 and visual web developer 2008 but the solution items are unavailable in both cases.Please suggest how to open this application

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the log4net configuration is done in the applications web.config you should be able to format logging to include the log time. According to [the PatternLayout](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Layout.PatternLayout.html) conversion patterns, you can use the %date specifier for this.

As for the message size, are you looking for the length of the message string?